# How to log output in the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework?

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, testing

I would like to log output test data when running test with the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework. I could go around it by creating some element and writing it on that however this feels like a hacked way. Is there any framework supported way of writing output during testing?

Comment: I believe Jeff Wilcox is going to be releasing this soon. I think it is some kind of HTTP handler that the unit test client sends the results back to as it executes.

Comment: this question got old, now there is a way to do it and yet I can't find it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the basic code was all there in the April2010 toolkit but never quite finished.    The idea is to have your TestClass have a `TestContext TestContext {get; set;}` property that the framework will automatically set.  Then, in a TestMethod, call `TestContext.WriteLine()`

In the visual output for a test method, there is a "Output" section but it's databinding was set to a property that did not exist. 
I've created patch 10660 to address the issue.  Hopefully it will be fixed for SL5's release.
http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=silverlight&DownloadId=295575

Copy the patch's files over April 2010 Silverlight Toolkit  unzipped Infrastructure.zip, replacing originals, and build your own copy of Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.dll

Answer (score 1):

The next release of the Silverlight Toolkit (after the October 2009 release) will have an experimental componen, used by the team, for this purpose. Though I can't commit to a date, I envision this happening in the current calendar year.

Comment: Hey Jeff--- did this ever happen? I can see `UnitTestContext` (in `Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.UnitTesting.Metadata.VisualStudio`) but  `UnitTestContext.WriteLine()` does not output to the Silverlight UI (like the Output: section)...

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [StatLight](http://Statlight.net) to get console report, XML report, or integrate with teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Lighthouse Silverlight Unit Test Runner](http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/)

It works out of the box and provides standardized xml results file, and also outputs rich logging to the console.